# How to add text on a solid in Three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm working on a project where I have to put a text vertically on a solid more particularly on a cylinder. I just started to learn Three.js for this project.
Once this done, I would like to replace the cylinder with an .obj file and I would like to know if there is a smarter way to get to my final result which is a vertical text on an object file.

I searched in the Three.js documentation how to put text on a solid, but I did not find anything.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body {
            margin: 0;
            }
            canvas {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            }
        </style>
        <title>Test</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/106/three.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/three@0.85.0/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
        <script>
            var scene = new THREE.Scene();
            var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

            var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
            document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

            window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
                var width = window.innerWidth;
                var height = window.innerHeight;
                renderer.setSize(width, height); 
                camera.aspect = width/height;
                camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
            });

            controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

            var geometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(1,1,5,64,64);
            var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0x00f9ff, side:THREE.DoubleSide, wireframe: true});
            var cone = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
            scene.add(cone);

            // create a point light
            var pointLight = new THREE.PointLight( 0xFFFFFF );

            // set its position
            pointLight.position.x = 10;
            pointLight.position.y = 50;
            pointLight.position.z = 130;

            // add to the scene
            scene.add(pointLight);

            camera.position.z = 3;

            var render = function () {
                requestAnimationFrame(render);
                // cone.rotation.y += 0.01;
                renderer.render(scene, camera);
            };

            render();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you run this page, you'll just see a cylinder. I would to know and to understand where in the code I should put the lines to show the text on the cylinder and if I can easily replace the cylinder with an object file, or should I put the object before.

Comment: This potentially a complex problem to solve. [DecalGeometry](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#examples/en/geometries/DecalGeometry) come to mind as possible solution, check this example: https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_decals

Comment: Have you considered placing the text as a texture?

Comment: Yes and it is still not working. Maybe, I'm not coding it in the right way because I'm new to Three.js. I even tried with DecalGeometry (Thanks for help, @ScieCode btw).

Comment: I finally made it with using TextGeometry. Not really beautiful to see, but it's working.